# Is it possible to add additional rows to mysql array result then looped in smarty?

Tags: php, mysql, smarty

I'm new to smarty. I tried to loop a mysql query.

My view.php:

```
require 'libs/smarty.class.php';
$smarty = new Smarty;
include("connection.inc.php");

$query = "SELECT * FROM quickcount group by regency";
$result= mysql_db_query($db, $query, $connection) or
die("query error!");


while($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $data[]=$res;
}

$smarty->assign('qc',$data);
$smarty->display('view.tpl');
?>
```

My view.tpl:

```
{section name=i loop=$qc}
<tr>
<td>{$qc[i].regency}</td>          
<td>{$qc[i].vote1}</td>
<td>{$qc[i].vote2}</td>
<td>{$qc[i].vote3}</td>
<td>{$qc[i].vote4}</td>
</tr>
{/section}
```

Those two files above worked well, but the problem came up when I wanted to add one more column in my output table. Let's say the new column is "total" (vote1+vote2+vote3+vote4).

I tried this in my view.php and failed:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM quickcount group by regency";
$result= mysql_db_query($db, $query, $connection) or
die("query error!");

while($res=mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
    $data[]=$res;
    $vote1 = $res[3];
    $vote2 = $res[4];
    $vote3 = $res[5];
    $vote4 = $res[6];

    $totals=$vote1+$vote2+$vote3+$vote4;
    $total=array($totals);
}

$smarty->assign('qc',$data);
$smarty->assign('total',$total);
$smarty->display('view.tpl');
```

I want to add percentages as well.

Can anyone help?

Comment: You **really** should not be writing code that relies on `mysql_` functions anymore. The MySQL extension has been deprecated for years (ever notice these red warning boxes in the documentation?) and is about to be dropped in the upcoming PHP7 release, which can be released any time now. Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). On an up-to-date server, this code has a life span of about a month, after which it will **stop working**.

Comment: What do you mean by "failed"? It returns an error, doesn't show anything, the cell is empty,....?

Comment: It shows only one row (the last row)